# In view testing,client put and delete method is not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

```
#views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Order,Pizza,Box,Topping
from .serializers import OrderSummarySerializer ,ToppingSerializer,BoxSerializer,PizzaSerializer

class OrderListAndDetailApiView(APIView):
    # 1. List all
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
 
        order = Order.objects.filter(user = request.user.id)
        print(order)
        serializer = OrderSummarySerializer(order, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # 2. Create
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
        print("request body is  your request.data",request.data)
        print("request id:",request.user.id)
        data = {
            'customer': request.data.get('customer'), 
            'address': request.data.get('address'), 
            'user': request.user.id
        }
        serializer = OrderSummarySerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

   
    def get_object(self, order_id, user_id):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(id=order_id,user = user_id)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    # 3. update
    def put(self, request, order_id, *args, **kwargs):
        order_instance = self.get_object(order_id,request.user.id)

            return Response(
                {"res": "Object with order id does not exists"}, 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        data = {
            'customer': request.data.get('customer'), 
            'address': request.data.get('address'), 
            'user': request.user.id
        }
        serializer = OrderSummarySerializer(instance = order_instance, data=data, partial = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 4. Delete
    def delete(self, request,order_id,*args, **kwargs):
        order_instance = self.get_object(order_id,request.user.id)
        if not order_instance:
            return Response(
                {"res": "Object with order id does not exists"}, 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        order_instance.delete()
        return Response(
            {"res": "Object deleted!"},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )      
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    OrderListAndDetailApiView
    
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('order', OrderListAndDetailApiView.as_view(),name="order"),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/',OrderListAndDetailApiView.as_view(),name="details")
]
#test.py
import json
from django.test import TestCase,Client
from django.urls import reverse
from ..models import Order
from ..serializers import OrderSummarySerializer
from rest_framework import status
  
client = Client() 

class UpdateSingleOrderTest(TestCase):
  
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = Order.objects.create(
           id="1",customer="abc",address="mno")
        self.b = Order.objects.create(
            id="2",customer="xyz",address="mnop")
        self.valid_payload = {
            "customer": "aaaaa",
            "address": "uuuu",
        }
        self.invalid_payload = {
            "customer": "yyyy",
            "address": "",
        }

    def test_valid_update_order(self):
        response = self.client.put(
            reverse('details', args=[1]),
            data=json.dumps(self.valid_payload),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def test_invalid_update_order(self):
        response = self.client.put(
            reverse('details',args=[1]),
            data=json.dumps(self.invalid_payload),
            content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class DeleteSingleOrderTest(TestCase):
    order_url=reverse('details', args=[2])

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = Order.objects.create(
           id="1",customer="ttt",address="iiii")
        self.b = Order.objects.create(
            id="2",customer="vvvv",address="yyyy")
        

    def test_valid_delete_order(self):
        response = self.client.delete(self.order_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def test_invalid_delete_order(self):
        response = self. client.delete(
           self.order_url)
        self.a.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

#Test result
FAIL: test_invalid_delete_order (Application.test.test_api.DeleteSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 157, in test_invalid_delete_order
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
AssertionError: 200 != 404

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_valid_delete_order (Application.test.test_api.DeleteSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 151, in test_valid_delete_order        
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
AssertionError: 200 != 204

======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_invalid_single_Order (Application.test.test_api.GetSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 70, in test_get_invalid_single_Order   
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
AssertionError: 200 != 404

======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_valid_single_Order (Application.test.test_api.GetSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 63, in test_get_valid_single_Order     
    self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)


======================================================================
FAIL: test_invalid_update_order (Application.test.test_api.UpdateSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 133, in test_invalid_update_order      
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
AssertionError: 200 != 400

======================================================================
FAIL: test_valid_update_order (Application.test.test_api.UpdateSingleOrderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:2.PIZZA\ProjectPizza\Application\test\test_api.py", line 126, in test_valid_update_order        
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
AssertionError: 200 != 204

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.091s

FAILED (failures=6)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: Fix your response status codes in views.